# spring out oauth2: authorization service security settings

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've deployed an `authorization server`.

By other side, I've a service is using `spring-security-oauth2-client` dependency in order to get a token from previously deployed `authorization server`.

`authorization-server` is really straightforward. I mean, it has any configuration class, and only has next configuration:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: trace

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          oidc-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "rdocelec"
              client-secret: "{noop}xxx"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "client_credentials"
              scopes:
                - "api"
            require-authorization-consent: true
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting UNAUTHORIZED responses when my `service` is starting and trying to get oauth2 authrozation server openid configuration fetching at:

- `_/.well-known/openid-configuration`
- `_/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server`

```
HTTP GET http://oauthz:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration
Accept=[application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json]
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@20395afe5 pairs: {GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.21}{Host: oauthz:8080}{Connection: keep-alive}
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@4b1339bf16 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401}{Vary: Origin}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 0}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{Content-Length: 0}{Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 10:34:41 GMT}{Keep-Alive: timeout=60}{Connection: keep-alive}
Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
HTTP GET http://oauthz:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration
Accept=[application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json]
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@451f08ea5 pairs: {GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.21}{Host: oauthz:8080}{Connection: keep-alive}
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@dcf495c16 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401}{Vary: Origin}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 0}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{Content-Length: 0}{Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 10:34:41 GMT}{Keep-Alive: timeout=60}{Connection: keep-alive}
Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
HTTP GET http://oauthz:8080/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server
Accept=[application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json]
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@60610a2b5 pairs: {GET /.well-known/oauth-authorization-server HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.21}{Host: oauthz:8080}{Connection: keep-alive}
sun.net.www.MessageHeader@420dee8216 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401}{Vary: Origin}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 0}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"}{Content-Length: 0}{Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 10:34:41 GMT}{Keep-Alive: timeout=60}{Connection: keep-alive}
Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

`authorization service` pom.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>oautz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauthz</name>
    <description>Oauth Authorization server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>oauthz</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Locally, this problem not arises. I mean, I'm referencing to my `authorization service` by `http://localhost:8080`.

I've deployed above services into our testing environment. Tehre, my `authorization service` is referenced using `http://oauthz:8080`.

I think I need to allow something into my `authorization service`, but I don't quite figure out what I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a scope `openid` to use Openid.

```yaml
scopes:
   - "api"
   - openid
```